# Failed update-what to do about it?

Tags: updates, graphic-drivers

[image: failed update message]

I have tried to update latest update today (9.11.2011 or 11.9.2011 if you are American...)
and got the error message shown above.

What should I do to solve this issue, please?

using EOS 6 Odin

Comment: seems like I am not the only one... https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cant-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04-2-kernel-version-5-8-0-55/180785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of interweb search I have eventually discovered:

```
sudo apt remove purge *nvidia*
```

that has sorted things out and eventually after re-starting things have sorted themselves out...

I know enough to be dangerous - you follow me at your own peril :-)

***update 12.02.2022:***

had the same problem on another PC and struggling :-(

purging doesn't seem to be working...

***an hour later..***.

tried updating nvidia drivers and ended up with black screen

bugger...

the solution[image]

source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver