# How can I fix unmet dependencies update error

Tags: updates, appcenter, dependencies

How can I fix unmet dependencies update error?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-38-generic: Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-470 (<= 470.74-1) but 470.82.00-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the solution that has worked for me (I have posted the same issue just before you):

[Failed update-what to do about it?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29124/failed-update-what-to-do-about-it/29126#29126)